# Additional white Space after Footer in Angular application

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an Angular 6 application along with bootstrap 4. The issue I am facing is there is an extra space after my footer and which looks very odd. My app.component.html has code as below

```
<app-header></app-header>    
<router-outlet></router-outlet>    
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The app-header has content in the form of navbar,the router-outlet holds dynamic content as per the routing urls.The app-footer has footer content as below

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: rgb(209, 226, 230);">
  <br> 
  This is my footer
</div>
```

If the dynamic content inside the router-outlet is more in size the footer sticks to the bottom perfectly but if the content is small in size the footer moves up and leaves an additional space below it which does not seem to be coming due to any tag. So where is this additional space coming from?

[image: additional space]

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer:**

You can set `min-height: 80vh` to your contact block thus, it will occupy **at least** 80% of the height of the **viewport** and the footer will appear near the bottom of the screen.

---

**Original answer:**

If you want your footer to always be at the bottom you can use:

```
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
```

Here is a working example:

```css
footer{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(209, 226, 230);
  padding-top:1rem;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>Contact Us</h1></div>
<footer>This is my footer</footer>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply. This works fine for the contact us page(my footer moves at the bottom of my page) but my home page has a 3 carousel sliders one after another and now it happens that my footer overlaps on the first carousel of the home page since (position:absolute is what we have defined in css).If I use (position:relative)  my home page works fine but again in contact us page footer moves up.So in both the cases one is compromised over the other.

Comment: You know, what you see is **relative to the size of your window**, a user on mobile will see the footer at the bottom while a user with a very large screen will see the footer as on your screenshot. Maybe what you want to do is set a `min-height: 80vh` to your contact block thus, it will occupy **at least** 80% of the **height of the viewport** and the footer will appear near the bottom of the screen. (Remove the `position:absolute` if you do that.)

Comment: Ok I tried by removing the position:absolute and adding the min-height: 80vh. And this works perfectly for me.This is what I was looking for.So the vh or viewport height works in this case.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried by removing the position:absolute and adding the min-height: 80vh. And this works perfectly for me.This is what I was looking for.So the vh or viewport height works in this case.